# Variable in VBA doesn't change

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to make a new table from some information in a table, with an 
structure like this:

```
A    B    D   G  L
A    B    D   G  M
A    B    D   H  N
A    B    E   I  O
A    C    F   J  P
A    C    F   K  Q
```

So, It returns a table with rows like this:

```
A  |  D |  B |  "G: L M   H: N"
```

The original data base has the following columns:

- Role
- Object
- Instance
- Field
- Value

The new table should be: Role, Instance, Object, Object value. So, if the object is the same, it means it's a new instance for that object, an it's new value will be every field(with all it's values), like the example above.

This is the code (The text is supposed to be in the first 5 columns, and it should be returned from the G column):

```
Sub instancia()

Dim fila, filacol As Long

Dim cad, c As String

fila = 2
filacol = 2

Do
    cad = ""

    Cells(filacol, 7) = Cells(fila, 1)
    Cells(filacol, 8) = Cells(fila, 3)
    Cells(filacol, 9) = Cells(fila, 2)

    Do
        c = " "
        cad = cad + Cells(fila, 4).Value + ": "
        Do
            c = c + Cells(fila, 5).Value + " "
            fila = fila + 1
        Loop While Cells(fila, 4) = Cells(fila + 1, 4)

        cad = cad + c
    Loop While Cells(fila, 2).Value = Cells(fila + 1, 2).Value
    Cells(filacol, 10).Value = car
    filacol = filacol + 1

Loop While Cells(fila + 1, 2) <> Empty

End Sub
```

It does't work because it says there's a problem with execution time, but trying to debug, I found out that the variable 'fila' never changes. What can I do?

Comment: Put break points at first line after each Do and step through. Other issues is that in VBA, proper concatenate strings with `&`. Is the `car` a typo? Is `fila` supposed to be a row and `filacol` a column counter:
 `Cells(RowNumber,ColumnNumber)`. To test empty cells: `IsEmpty(Range)`. `Loop While Rng <> Empty` should go `Loop Until IsEmpty(Rng)`. You can put `Debug.Print ` lines here and there to display values in Immediate window.

Comment: Also, if `fila` is a row, you should declare it as a `Long`, and not as a `Variant` as you have in your code.